# syntax error near unexpected token 'elif'

Tags: bash, syntax

I get the error on the 7th line. Any ideas? I checked for spaces and there are none.

```
#!/bin/bash
if test $# -eq 0
then
    echo "No arguments"
elif test $# -eq 1
    echo "$1"
elif test $# -eq 2
    echo "$1 $2"
else
    echo "More than 2 arguments"
fi
```

Comment: Are your quotes actually `“` and `”`? Can you make sure they are `"` throughout?

Comment: Yes all quotes are " and not '

Comment: plug for shellcheck.net

Comment: @KyanHamad: That isn't what Doug was getting at.  The quotes you pasted here are curly quotes generally created in programs like microsoft word and will not work in code.  You need to ensure you have straight quotes, regardless if it is a double or single quote.

Comment: @Jesse_b I was using straight quotes. The issue I found out was that I needed to use then statements after the elif as well as quoting the $#. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: On a first look I was half sure this was a CRLF issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for if/elif/else/fi requires a `then` after each "elif":

```
#!/bin/bash
if test "$#" -eq 0
then
    printf 'No arguments\n'
elif test "$#" -eq 1
then
    printf '%s\n' "$1"
elif test "$#" -eq 2
then
    printf '%s %s\n' "$1" "$2"
else
    printf 'More than 2 arguments\n'
fi
```

I've also [replaced your `echo`s with `printf`s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/117549) and [quoted the instances of $#](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/117549).

Answer (score 2):

You need a `then` after `elif`.

```
#!/bin/bash
if test $# -eq 0
then
    echo "No arguments"
elif test $# -eq 1
then
    echo "$1"
elif test $# -eq 2
then
    echo "$1 $2"
else
    echo "More than 2 arguments"
fi
```